# Нужные картинки для Facebook в блоке "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы предлагались нужные картинки при размещении в facebook? Я пользуюсь кодом из Яндекса: http://api.yandex.ru/share/

Comment: Переформулируйте свой вопрос, лично я не смог понять смысла вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

1) Добавляем к тегу НТМЛ вот так:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

2) Добавляем заголовки:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://САЙТ/СТРАНИЦА.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://САЙТ/КАРТИНКА.jpg"/> 
<link rel="image_src" href="http://САЙТ/КАРТИНКА.jpg" />
```

ЮРЛ тоже желательно указывать (он там значится в стандарте).
Да. Кстати. Важно помнить, что фейсбук загружает страницу только ОДИН раз при обращении (добавлении) первым пользователем и на все изменения после этого не реагирует.